# sed command creates a file with 0 bytes

Tags: shell, sed

I have a shell script which copies an xml file and places it a directory. Now once the xml is copied, I perform a `sed` operation to replace a tag value with some other value. I am using the following command:

```
sed "s#ABC-XYZ#DEF-PQR#g" test.xml > test-newfile.xml
```

The command executes properly but it creates the new xml "test-newfile.xml" with size 0 bytes. So I guess, this command is working but somehow not able to create the new copy of the xml.

The `test.xml` is not empty:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sujeet11 sujeet   0 May 28 23:06 test-newfile.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sujeet11 sujeet 555 May 28 23:04 test.xml
```

Now here is the interesting part:
If I open the test.xml in vi mode and without making any changes to the xml, if I save it using :wq and then perform the same sed operation, it substitutes the string and creates the newfile copy with the updated string.

Comment: I assume "executes properly" means "exits with a 0 status", so the next most obvious thing that comes to mind is that the source file `test.xml` is empty.

Comment: Can you show some sample input?

Comment: In future, please edit the extra information into the question rather than adding it as a comment.

Comment: Yes, exact code..havent used the exact string here though, but its something similar

Comment: First of all, split your problem into components to be able to understand its origin. Try the following:`sed -e 's#ABC-DEF#MNO-PQR#g' test.xml` and check that `sed` produces expected output to stdout. If it does, then check that you can create non-empty files in that folder (use any text editor or just `echo 'some text' > test-new.xml`. Then combine the two commands.

Comment: Are you working on Windows?  It sounds as if you're missing a newline at the end of the file (and there's only one line of data in the file).  When you edit, `vim` will add the newline.  I was trying that as a possible source of trouble; both GNU `sed` and BSD `sed` on Mac OS X 10.9.3 are OK with a file consisting of a null byte, 500 x's and no newline (or the same with a newline at the end).  I got an empty file when I created a file of 500 copies of 0xC0 byte (invalid code in a UTF-8 file — my terminal/locale uses UTF-8).

Comment: I tried the following:
sed -e 's#ABC-DEF#MNO-PQR#g' test.xml 
It does not produce output in stdout, no errors, just comes back to teh prompt.

Comment: Yes, the complete XML is in one line.

Comment: Does the failing `test.xml` end with a newline?  Does the copy of the file edited with `vim` end with a newline?  If the one fails and the other succeeds, that is the problem — text files are supposed to end with a newline, and you invoke undefined behaviour if the file does not end with a newline.  Many versions of `sed` will work anyway; some will not.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The failing test.xml does not end with a new line. Once i edit it with vim, it ends with a newline. Thanks!
How am i going to take care of it? any other method to append a new line before performing the sed operation?

Comment: It might be easiest to use `echo "" >>test.xml` to add a newline to the end of the file regardless of whether one exists already.  You can then use `sed -e 's#ABC-DEF#MNO-PQR#g' -e '/^$/d' test.xml` to eliminate empty lines (or `-e '$/^$/d'` to remove an empty final line in the file), undoing the damage wrought by the `echo` if the file already ended with a newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring some comments into an answer.*</sup>

It sounds as if you're missing a newline at the end of the file (and there's only one line of data in the file). When you edit, `vim` will add the newline. I was trying that as a possible source of trouble; both GNU `sed` and BSD `sed` on Mac OS X 10.9.3 are OK with a file consisting of a null byte, 500 x's and no newline (or the same with a newline at the end).

Does the failing `test.xml` end with a newline? Does the copy of the file edited with `vim` end with a newline? If the one fails and the other succeeds, that is the problem — text files are supposed to end with a newline, and you invoke undefined behaviour if the file does not end with a newline. Many versions of `sed` will work anyway; some will not.

> Yes, you are right. The failing `test.xml` does not end with a new line. Once I edit it with `vim`, it ends with a newline. Thanks! How am I going to take care of it? Any other method to append a new line before performing the sed operation?

It might be easiest to add a newline to the end of the file regardless of whether one exists already, maybe using:

```
echo "" >>test.xml
```

You can then use:

```
sed -e 's#ABC-XYZ#DEF-PQR#g' -e '/^$/d' test.xml
```

to eliminate all empty lines (or `-e '${/^$/d;}'` to remove an empty final line in the file), undoing the damage wrought by the echo if the file already ended with a newline.

Comment: Yes, that worked fine! Thanks a lot Jonathan for the help. :) Really appreciate it.