# Missing newline character?

Tags: linux, shell, hdfs

I've copied a file from HDFS into my local file system (all on RH linux). However, after the copy, if I `cat` the file, I see the following:

```
[me@ac12 ~]$ cat file_copy
0|name|string
1|phone|string
2|age|string[me@ac12 ~]$
```

What I expected was this:

```
[me@ac12 ~]$ cat file_copy
0|name|string
1|phone|string
2|age|string
[me@ac12 ~]$
```

You can see that a newline seems to be missing in the first cat, and the shell prompt is on the same line as the last line. Why would this be and how can I diagnose the issue?

EDIT: I can't edit the output file (well, maybe I could but I really don't want to - I'd rather fix the problem at the source). I want to know why there is no newline character..

Comment: 1. Check if your copy is the same as your original. (size, or even a hex dump (od command), or cksum should be ok.) 2. If they are the same, it probably means that your file does not contain the last 'new line'.  If you don't want to change the input file, then you need to do something like `cat file_copy; echo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `sed` to add a newline after last line:

```
sed -i.bak $'$s/$/\\n/' file_copy
```

**EDIT:**

Or else use (thanks to @JonathanLeffler):

```
echo '' >> file_copy
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I edited my question - I would rather figure out why the newline is missing rather than fix it every time I have to copy the file from HDFS..

Comment: There might be issues with the editor/tool you used to create your file and/or the issues with file transfer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to suspect there is a bug in the code that generated the file. Fortunately it's open source and I'm going to start debugging it now!

Comment: Well, it works, but it is a heavy duty approach.  What's up with `echo '' >>file_copy`, which simply adds a newline to the end of the file?

Comment: Yes thanks @JonathanLeffler: that should definitely work. I probably got swayed by inline editing benefit of `sed` command.

Comment: See also [`sed` command creates a file with 0 bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925401/sed-command-creates-a-file-with-0-bytes/23925944#23925944) for another version of this problem.

Comment: Why does echo '' >> file_copy add a newline to the end of the file?

Comment: Because `echo` by default writes a new line on stdout. `echo ''` will just output a newline.