# Insert an endline character at the end of file in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, eof

I am trying to check if a file has already EOF character is so do nothing, if not then add a new line characer to the end of the file in shell script.

currently i am using :

```
sed -i -e '$a\' file
```

getting error message :  sed: Not a recognized flag: i

Comment: Use `echo '' >> file`

Comment: I do not believe this question should have been closed. A very relevant difference between this question and [Missing newline character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923317/missing-newline-character) is that in this question, it is not known in advance whether a file ends with a newline character.